# Can't install libraries on Visual Studio code

Tags: vcpkg

I downloaded vcpkg,  i managed to run the commands but whenever i try to install a library, the following error comes up :Error: while loading iostream:

The port directory (D:\New folder (2)\DEV\vcpkg\ports\iostream) does not exist
Error: failed to load port from D:\New folder (2)\DEV\vcpkg\ports\iostream
Note: Updating vcpkg by rerunning bootstrap-vcpkg may resolve this failure.

i tried updating vcpkg but it didnt work. I just started programming in c++ and i cant find a way to install libraries or whatever they are called . Is there any other way to install iostream and stuff like that?

sorry if this is a stupid question but im new and i didnt find anything that could have helped me.